# DateTime error Subtracting from 0 hour

Tags: c#, datetime, time, subtraction

Using C# DateTime, I'd like to subtract a time past 0 (or midnight). However, I get an error when doing so. I'm trying to create a timeline where you can zoom in and out and scroll through the times. I get the following error: "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime."

I guess DateTime doesn't know how to wrap back around from 0 to 23?  How do I get around this?

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Fyi, questions without enough information tend to get closed or down voted. Whenever possible, be sure to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It makes it much easier for others to help you figure the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subtract a `TimeSpan` from a `DateTime`, it will "wrap around" past midnight:

```
> var d1 = DateTime.Parse("4/11/2012 12:30:00 AM");
> var d2 = d1.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 15, 0));
> 
> d2
[4/10/2012 11:15:00 PM]
```

Comment: Unless it goes to less than `DateTime.MinValue`, as Jon Skeet posted in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10113564/1583).

Comment: Correct, but in what scenario would you want to represent a date/time less than `01/01/0001 00:00:00`? If you need `DateTime` to do that, you've most likely got bigger design problems.

Comment: Dunno. But without more information from the OP, we have _no idea_ what is attempted. How would you represent 10,000BC then?

Comment: Some other data structure besides a `DateTime`, on the rare occasion that you need to express BC times down to the millisecond (which is what `DateTime` is capable of). :)

Comment: You were both right. The problem was that since I only really cared about the hours, min, sec portion of the datetime, the dt object had been initialized to MinValue. So when I tried to subtract past midnight of that date it threw an error. I initialized the date to something else and it worked fine. thanks again!

Comment: @SpikeX: DateTime goes down to the tick (100 nanoseconds). And if you want BC functionality, use Noda Time :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're using the date which starts at `DateTime.MinValue`. If you subtract time such that it would go before `DateTime.MinValue`, you'll get that exception.

```
// This is equal to DateTime.MinValue - maybe you're doing this?
DateTime date = new DateTime();
// Bang
date = date.AddHours(-1);
```

If you *really* want a "just a time" representation, consider using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), my pseudo-port of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) with a rather richer type system than just `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting 5 minutes from a TimeSpan that is set to midnight results in -00:05. This results in a Timespan that is 23:55 rather than -00:05.

```
DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).TimeOfDay;
```